# Using the Current Mongoose Schema In A Schema Method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose Schema for messages. With this Schema, I declare a method, but inside this method I need to use the Message Schema to find other messages relating to the current message.

Since my method is not a `static` method, `this` references the current document. I am pretty sure that I cannot just do `this.findById(...)` because `this` is the current document, not the Schema model. The only other thing that I thought about doing, really doesn't sound like a good idea: Importing the Schema from the same file I am working it.

Does anyone know how to do this? Or can someone point me in the right direction?